# Asynchronous Call Not Working with URLSession

Tags: swift, nsurlsession, backendless

I am working with URLSession and a service called Backendless.  Backendless is very similar to Parse.

Backendless has a messaging service that allows you to send email.  I am using this for error reporting in my app.  I have created a method called sendErrorCodeEmail() that calls the Backendless method.  A simple example of how this works is shown below.

```
func callSendHTMLEmailInDelegate()
    {
        let errorCodeMessage = "There is an error."
        self.sendErrorCodeEmail(errorCodeMessage)
    }

func sendErrorCodeEmail(_ errorCode: String)
    {
        // Asynchronous Version
        let subject = "Error Called"
        let body = "\(errorCode)"
        let recipient = ["xx@xx.com"]

        self.backendless?.messagingService.sendHTMLEmail(subject, body: body, to: recipient, response: { (response : Any?) -> () in

            print("The error code email was sent successfully. \(response)")

        }, error:  { (fault : Fault?) -> () in

            print("The server reported a fault in the sendErrorCode email: \(fault)")
        })
    }
```

This works perfectly.

My issues is when I use sendHTMLEmail with a URLSession.  If I report an error due to a bad URL I call the same sendErrorCodeEmail() method.  The problem is, the sendHTMLEmail() method from Backendless does not execute. I have verified that sendErrorCodeEmail() is called.

Since the only difference in the code is the use of URLSession, I am wondering if there is a threading issue or something else I am missing.  sendHTMLEmail is an asynchronous method.  There is also a synchronous version and if I call this in sendErrorCodeEmail() it works.  The basic code using the URLSession is below.

```
func startSession()
    {
        // Start the connection with the URL that was passed in the unit method in the dataHandler.
        self.session = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = self.session!.dataTask(with: self.sessionURL!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            if error == nil
            {
                if data != nil
                {
                    print("Data was downloaded successfully")
                }
            }
            else if error != nil
            {
                self.sendErrorCodeEmail("There was an error")
            }
        })

        dataTask.resume()
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looking at the code, this will only reach the `self.sendErrorCodeEmail("There was an error")` code when error is not nil, there is another case where error is not nil but data is nil which you have not covered. add additional print statements / breakpoints and make sure the code is being reached. if its reaching the code and not working then tell us whats happening, are you getting errors?

Comment: @Scriptable the code was simplified to make it simple to read. The above issues are covered in production code.  Good points though. I appreciate the input. I didn't intend to be misleading.

Comment: no worries, just trying to fully understand the situation, looks like it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that there is a problem with calling `send` in the worker thread.

You could try do invoke the call in the main thread:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.sendErrorCodeEmail("There was an error")
}
```

Comment: Brilliant.  Thanks.  Is there a reason you new send was on the worker thread?  Is that the default action?  To put async calls on a thread other than main?

Comment: You'll have to check the documentation. It states that the completion handler of `dataTask` will be executed in the delegate queue (which you typically hand in when you create the `URLSession`). Since you use the singleton (`URLSession.shared`), this will use an arbitrary worker thread -- Although this is not clearly stated in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the help!